# Is there anyway to access the XML payload in HTTP Trigger of Google Cloud Function or Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Google/Firebase Cloud Functions appear very powerful for quick implementation of APIs. However, unlike Amazon and Azure, it seems that they auto convert to JSON payload and do NOT make the underlying payload available (req.body is empty) if the caller submitted application/xml or text/xml payload.

It is not always  in control to force the caller to submit JSON payload, especially for WebHooks type of operations.

Is there anyway to retrieve raw XML payload from the HTTP Trigger requests which we can then manually parse as xml and perform necessary operations.

thanks for your help.

Comment: HTTPS functions with Cloud Functions for Firebase is powered by Express.js.  The request and response objects are just Express Request and Response objects.  So, whatever you can do with Express, you can do with Cloud Functions.  https://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.rawBody.toString();
```

This does not work for now with the emulator, but it does work on Google's servers. I tested it on Firebase.

Note that you can't use request.pipe() (though it works with the emulator...) because the request payload is fully read before being handled to your function.

Discussion about this issue is here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36252545